# How can I stop adding blank elements to the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

With this code, I can add elements to mockapi, but even if it is empty. How can prevent this situation?

```
document.querySelector("#petForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name        = document.querySelector("#petName").value;
    const image       = document.querySelector("#petImage").value;
    const description = document.querySelector("#petDesc").value;
    const data = JSON.stringify({name, image, description});
    document.querySelector("#petSubmitButton").textContent = "Ekleniyor";
    document.querySelector("#petSubmitButton").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    if(window.isEditing){
        fetch(`${window.mockApiUrl}${window.isEditing}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: data,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
```

Comment: Which field is mandatory? As far as I can see, you have name, image & description.

You can do `const isDataPresent = !!name && !!image && description;` and then modify if condition to `if (window.isEditing && isDataPresent)`

Comment: If this resolves your issue, feel free to mark my answer down below as `accepted` as sign of confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which field is **mandatory** you can do it like this...

`const isDataPresent = !!name && !!image && description;`

Modify `if` condition to:
`if (window.isEditing && isDataPresent)`